# Rows inserted in mysql table after application started not picked by the application

Tags: python, mysql, database, python-3.x, mysql-python

I have usecase in whch I have to read `rows` having `status = 0` from mysql.

**Table schema:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS in_out_analytics(
                id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
                file_name VARCHAR(255), 
                start_time BIGINT, 
                end_time BIGINT,
                duration INT,
                in_count INT,
                out_count INT,
                status INT
            )
```

I am using this below code to read data from mysql.

**persistance.py**

```
import mysql
import mysql.connector
import conf

class DatabaseManager(object):
    # global vars to storing db connection details
    connection = None 

    def __init__(self): 
        self.ip = conf.db_ip
        self.user_name = conf.db_user
        self.password = conf.db_password
        self.db_name = conf.db_name

        # Initialize database only one time in application
        if not DatabaseManager.connection:
            self.connect()
        self.cursor = DatabaseManager.connection.cursor() 
        self.create_schema()

    def connect(self): 
        try: 
            DatabaseManager.connection = mysql.connector.connect(
                    host= self.ip, 
                    database = self.db_name,
                    user = self.user_name, 
                    password = self.password
            )
            print(f"Successfully connected to { self.ip } ") 
        except mysql.connector.Error as e: 
            print(str(e)) 

    def create_schema(self):
        # Create database
        # sql = f"CREATE DATABASE { self.db_name} IF NOT EXIST"
        # self.cursor.execute(sql)

        # Create table
        sql = """
            CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS in_out_analytics(
                id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
                file_name VARCHAR(255), 
                start_time BIGINT, 
                end_time BIGINT,
                duration INT,
                in_count INT,
                out_count INT,
                status INT
            )"""
        self.cursor.execute(sql)

    def read_unprocessed_rows(self):
        sql = "SELECT id, start_time, end_time FROM in_out_analytics WHERE status=0;"
        self.cursor.execute(sql) 
        result_set = self.cursor.fetchall()
        rows = []
        for row in result_set:
            id = row[0]
            start_time = row[1]
            end_time = row[2]
            details = {
                'id' : id,
                'start_time' : start_time,
                'end_time' : end_time
            }
            rows.append(details)
        return rows
```

**test.py**

```
import time
from persistance import DatabaseManager


if __name__ == "__main__":

    # Rows which are inserted after application is started do not get processed if  
    # 'DatabaseManager' is defined here
    # dm = DatabaseManager()

    while True:
        # Rows which are inserted after application is started do get processed if  
        # 'DatabaseManager' is defined here
        dm = DatabaseManager()

        unprocessed_rows = dm.read_unprocessed_rows()
        print(f"unprocessed_rows: { unprocessed_rows }")
        time.sleep(2)
```

**Problem:**

The problem is, when I define database object `dm = DatabaseManager()` above the while loop, then any new row which is inserted after the application is started do not get processed and if I define the `dm = DatabaseManager()` inside the while loop then the rows which are inserted even after application is started gets processed.

**What is the problem with the above code**?

Ideally, we should make only one object of `DatabaseManager` as this class is creating a connection with MySQL. Hence creating a connection with any database should be the ideal case.

Answer (score 0):

Making an assumption here, as I cannot test it myself.

**tl;dr:** Add `DatabaseManager.connection.commit()` to your `read_unprocessed_rows`

When you execute your SELECT statement, a transaction is created implicitly, using the default isolation level [REPEATABLE READ](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-transaction-isolation-levels.html#isolevel_repeatable-read). That creates a snapshot of the database at that point in time and all consecutive reads in that transaction will read from the snapshot established during the first read. The effects of different isolation levels are described [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-consistent-read.html). To refresh the snapshot in REPEATABLE READ, you can commit your current transaction before executing the next statement.

So, when you instantiate your `DatabaseManager` inside your loop, each SELECT starts a new transaction on a new connection, hence has a fresh snapshot every time. When instantiating your `Databasemanager` outside the loop, the transaction created by the first SELECT keeps the same snapshot for all consecutive SELECTs and updates from outside that transaction remain invisible.